# Allowing Drupal login using WHM, cPanel or WHMCS login details?

Tags: authentication, cpanel, whm, whmcs

Currently, I have decided to use Drupal as the primary login area where users can do stuff. Problem is, I want to automatically allow for the logging in of users using their cpanel, whm or whmcs login details. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't suggest you to do this.

You will only introduce more risks to all your systems, even if Drupal is a very secure system.

There are sometimes authentication security issues, with cPanel drupal and whmcs.  Now, imagine those security issues + the ones of drupal, + the ones on whmcs...

...with all these insecurity layers combined, it's a real security bomb, and not something that will help your customers that much you are going to create.   ...plus your modules for this will probably experience someday security issues also.

I suggest to take a look at other web hosts : if they don't do this, and if even whmcs do not bridge with vbulletin on their own website, there is a reason for this! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no module for this.

Also Drupal seems not to provide a direct way to connect 3rd party login systems.

Having a look at the LDAP integration (file `ldapauth.module`) in the package, you can use the hook `hook_form_alter`. The check whether the form is using `user_login_authenticate_validate` in the validate entry and replace it with their own authentication function.

Basically you can use the `ldapauth.module` file as a basis and start with the `ldapauth_login_authenticate_validate` function. 
In this function you have to add code that uses `$form_values['name'];` and `$form_values['pass']` and verify them against your cPanel database.

A completly different approach would be to write a cPanel module to create Drupal users and update the accounts. To get started you can have a look at [writing cPanel modules](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WritingCpanelModules).